# Why is my image not displaying on my Web page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

[image]

^
This is what is displayed when I go to the Website URL, as you can see it doesn't display anything just a broken image.

[image]

and then this is my code I inputted for it to display the image under my bucket name 'ronaldhoward'

If anyone knows why my image isn't displaying maybe cause I am using the wrong image input code? Not sure..

Comment: Is your image public? Can you provide any information about your setup?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I have my image in a S3 bucket that has 'Block Public Access' turned off which I assume means it's public. I just checked if the image itself in the S3 Bucket was public which I don't think it was even tho the S3 bucket itself is public, so I think that was the issue that you just helped me fix :) Thank you Marcin

Comment: I upvoted your comment, not sure how else to upvote.

Comment: You accepted the answer. That's enough. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by the **image not being public**. To make entire bucket or multiple objects in the bucket public in read-only mode, the bucket policy  outlined  in [Granting read-only permission to an anonymous user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2)  can be used.

Comment: Won't the image url change every now and then? How would I account for that.

Comment: @Decjk Change how? You can make generic bucket policy to allow for all files, not only that one specific image.

Comment: I mean like every time I launch my script it creates the bucket with the image inside but each time I have to manually add it to be Publicly viewed so it actually displays the image, what piece of code would do this for me or would it be a customization of some setting?